# Why does child measure still work while parent is collapsed?

Tags: wpf

I stumbled upon something interesting in WPF and I cannot explain this to myself.

Its a strange behavior.

The title basically explains everything.

Here is an example where I set Grid.Visibility to Collapsed and I invalidate measure of a control inside that Grid. The control is being remeasured even thought it shouldnt since in wpf controls that are not visible are not being measured.

```
public class MyControl : Button
{
    public MyAnotherControl AnotherControl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Grid Grid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        return new Size(100, 20);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
        return arrangeBounds;
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        AnotherControl.InvalidateMeasure();
        base.OnClick();
    }
}
```

This is my another control which is inside Grid.

```
public class MyAnotherControl : Button
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        Console.WriteLine("Measure called");
        return new Size(100, 10);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
        return arrangeBounds;
    }
}
```

This is XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:MyControl Background="Blue" Grid="{x:Reference grid}" AnotherControl="{x:Reference anotherControl}"/>
            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                <local:MyAnotherControl Content="{Binding}" Background="Red" x:Name="anotherControl"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

As you can see OnClick I change Grid.Visibility and invalidate measure of a grid's inner control.

According to MSDN:

Elements where Visibility is not Visible do not participate in input events (or commands), do not influence either the Measure or Arrange passes of layout, are not in a tab sequence, and will not be reported in hit testing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx

The question is why is MyAnotherControl being measured when it shouldnt?

If I change my code to Grid being collapsed from start on, MyAnotherControl is not being re-measured anymore when invalidating measure. Which represents correct wpf behavior.

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:MyControl Background="Blue" Grid="{x:Reference grid}" AnotherControl="{x:Reference anotherControl}"/>
            <Grid x:Name="grid" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <local:MyAnotherControl Content="{Binding}" Background="Red" x:Name="anotherControl"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

It seems to make difference whether you set Visibility right from start on or not.

Any ideas? I would appreciate your suggestions and ideas very much guys.

Comment: hi @dev-hedgehog  I think this is one of those semantically correct wrong behaviour instances that crops up from time to time:  the visibility of the MyAnotherControl was visible, so was included in measure etc.  however when the grid is collapsed the MyAnotherControl visibility is left untouched, and is hence still visible, so you can measure it even if not see it, because its containing parent is collapsed and you cant see the actual content, but it still exists....sort of a stealth object to test and try your patience.

Comment: Cont from above:
Cant test this out more until I get home to my dev machine, but let me know and I can get back to you

Comment: @GMasucci pretty sure you are correct. Visiblity does not inherit. Best thing you can do is walk up the visual tree and that is always a grizzly piece of code to justify. Note that OnRender() won't be called on elements that are not shown.

Comment: @GMasucci I think you are slightly wrong.It works when visibility is collapsed right on start. There are many queues in wpf and one is a measure queue managed by a LayoutManager which checks whenever you invalidate measure of a control whether one of the parents is collapsed. If not it will add the control to measured-to-be queue That is why its working correctly when I set visibility to collapsed right on start. I cannot explain why its not working inside OnClick. Btw I reflactored code from LayoutManager in wpf thats how I know basically whats going on but cant explain this

Comment: @Gusdor Why is it working when I change Visibility right on start? The inner control is not being remeasure even though i call InvalidateMeasure()? It works on start but not when done inside OnClick.

Comment: @devhedgehog likely because your element has not yet been loaded and, until loaded, collapsed if the default value.

Comment: @dev-hedgehog have you tried setting the visibility of MyAnotherControl to hidden or collapsed before you collapse the parent container, and then at the end of the `onclick()` event call for an update?  I know it seems like a superfluous couple of steps but worth trying to verify how things are working.

Comment: @Gusdor Loaded has nothing to do with this. I invalidate measure of MyAnotherControl on click. And to be able to click on anything of course everything shall be loaded. :) Still when I set visibility to collapsed on start and I click on that button to invalidate measure the re-measuring is not being executed. That is normal wpf behavior. Though when I do everything inside click means I change visibility of grid and invalidate measure of MyAnotherControl which is inside the Grid. The re-measuring triggers. That shouldnt happen according to wpf documentation. The question is why is it happening.

Comment: @GMasucci Its a good idea and I will try to set both grid and MyAnotherControl to collapsed before firing MyAnotherControl.InvalidateMeasure(). I will let you know about the result. But I guess the MyAnotherControl is this time itself completely collapsed so therefore no checking if parent is collapsed will be excuted.

Comment: Every wpf control needs to check if it shall be measured or not. Cases where wpf control doesnt measure is when its not visible or any of the parents is not visible. I seem to found out somehow to break that behavior hehehehe

Comment: lol a proper programmer then, if it works break it and then find out how:)

Comment: As expected setting visibility directly on MyAnotherControl which is inside Grid completely "disables" against any manipulations and tries to re-measure. But this should also happen when visibility is changed on Grid since MyAnotherControl is Grid's child. Once parent is collapsed and not being measured, the children shouldnt be either. Super strange behavior. :) @GMasucci yea, break it and put it back together and then you know how it works.

Comment: @GMasucci I found the answer. Visibility is not inhertable.

Comment: I was sure it wasn't however without my dev machine being on I have no system to back up what I thought, and with my luck if I make any statement without checking it it turns out to be the exact opposite... (references provided gladly by my wife if needed).

Comment: Every time I have had to deal with visibility I always have to do it manually, as I am mainly a C++/OpenGL dev I have put that down to lack of knowledge. Good to find out that its a requirement though. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh stupid thing is still visible internally even though parent is collapsed and user doesnt see it. Thats the answer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx